# Disable Auto Login Windows 7 (and missing account icons)

Tags: windows, windows-7

Running into a strange issue with a Windows 7 image.  Three years ago, I wrote a Powershell script which took a basic Windows 7 image (with only the Administrator account on it) and the script adds all the user accounts, applications, programs, regedits, et al.  Used sysprep to complete the image so it could be cloned using Clonezilla onto several hundred computers and go out to different sites, as well as create replacement PCs down the line.

Those original PCs we used ran out and we got a different line of PCs from the same maker, again with a Windows 7 operating system and just an Administrator account.  Found out this time the person who created that basic image for me did not put a password on the Administrator account as they did the first time, so it was automatically logging on for me.  Added a password to the Administrator account so it wouldn't auto-login.

Ran my script after making some edits to bring applications up to date.  Now after rebooting, it not only tries to Auto logon (despite everything I've checked to make sure Auto logon was disabled), but when you click OK to get past the Auto login error, it only shows the Administrator account instead of showing Administrator along with the other two account icons.  You then have to click "Switch user" and it will show only "Administrator" and "other user". You have to click on "other user" and input your account name and password.

How do I get it back to showing me all three account icons - Administrator plus my other two user accounts - after a reboot?

PS - these images were loaded onto the PCs by a person from another dept.  Same person three years ago as currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered from a worker in another dept that Microsoft changed Windows 7 so that the last user logged in is the icon that is shown after logging off or rebooting.  Love how Microsoft always "fixes" things that don't need fixing.